# FormatCondition Font Bold from C# Excel Interop not working

Tags: c#, excel, interop, excel-interop

I'm adding a new FormatCondition to a cell and trying to set some formatting:

```
Excel.FormatCondition cond = ExcelUtils.AddConditionExpression( .... );
cond.Font.Color = 5287936;
cond.Font.Bold = true;
```

Setting the color works fine, setting Bold to true doesn't (cond.Font.Bold is still System.DBNull after the assignment) and when I inspect the newly created conditional formatting in Excel I only see the color.

Has this happened to anyone else ? Please help!

Thanks

Comment: can you please share more backgound code? especially on the ExcelUtils namespace. what do you expect to see as a result?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue` instead of the plain Boolean value of true.  MS Word interop has similar requirements.  In the case of a Word Range, you have to cast the Bold value to an integer:

```
textRange.Font.Bold = (int) Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
```